# table td is not collapsing

Tags: html, css

I have a `table` inside another `table`. My HTML code is like below.

```
<td>
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="remind_when"><label>sfd</label></td>
      <td class="remind_when"><label>sdfasdf</label></td>
      <td class="remind_when"><label>sadfasf</label></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>                                                   
</td>
```

My CSS code is like below

```
.remind_when{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Only elements that display as `table-*` will collapse their borders. You have made the `td` elements `display: inline-block` so they won't.

So don't do that.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for your reply. But I am missing `border-radius: 5px;`. How can I get `border-radius` ?

Comment: You can't collapse borders so that two cells share the same adjacent border *and* round the corners of it.